# Is there a Built-in Python Function than can replace values in a certain list positions depending on a given condition?

Tags: python

I need a Python function to replace the value in a at a given index by the value in b at the same index if the value in c at that index is True.

```
a = [10, 100, 1000] # Values
b = [1,  50, 2000] # Candidate values

c = [True, False, False] # Mask
```

```
a[c] = b[c]

a = [1, 100, 1000]
```

I've been trying to optimize this piece of code that makes the trick:

```
def criteria(a,b,m):
  if m: return b
  else: return a
```

```
a = [criteria(a_e, b_e, c_e) for a_e, b_e, c_e in zip(a,b,c)]
```

but, because I'll be making a lot of masks and in the process, the best case in the first scenario is o(1) (because we know already the positions that we want to change), but in the second scenario is always o(n), because we are creating a new list iterating for all values.

Many thanks, have a nice day

Comment: The first scenario for normal python lists is an error. Even if it were to work it is not O(1). All values in `a` potentially need to be modified in the worst case.

Comment: If you're working with numbers only, you might want to look into numpy's boolean indexing options. You however will never be getting o(1) with your current problem.

Comment: This code is always O(N), I have no idea what you mean by "in the first scenario is o(1)"